# Laravel Route is not working on live server

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel forge to deploy the application. The form submission on the local server works fine. It finds the right route declared in the route file. But it does not work on the live server. On live server when I hit submit button I got "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message.

What could be the reasons?  I will highly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Here are the routes declared:

```
Route::get('/training/seo/outreach/brochure','BrochureDownloadController@index');
Route::post('/training/seo/outreach/brochure','BrochureDownloadController@store');
```

Here is the code on form

```
<form class="js-validate" method="post" id="brochure_download" name="brochure_download" action="{{ action('BrochureDownloadController@store')}}">
        {{ csrf_field()}}
```

Deploy Script ( On forge)

```
cd /home/forge/www.xponent.com.bd
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.2-fpm reloadif [ -f artisan ]
then
  php artisan migrate --force
fi
```

Comment: add one more artisan command. php artisan config:cache

Comment: clear storage/laravel.log, and hit the website again and let us know what is the content of laravel.log file so we can debug it.

Comment: Use php artisan route:cache to apply new changes for routes

Comment: Thanks @EmtiazZahid. After adding the php artisan config:cache command, it now works now.

Comment: You are welcome :) please check my answer to set it as solution.

Comment: @wblteam Please mark the answer as a solution in order to help community!

Comment: @staskrak done. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update your script**

Add `php artisan config:cache`

```
cd /home/forge/www.xponent.com.bd
git pull origin master
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
echo "" | sudo -S service php7.2-fpm reloadif [ -f artisan ]
then
  php artisan migrate --force
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Please run below command:

```
php artisan config:cache

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan route:clear
```